# MySQL Database with one user for Analysis only

Tags: mysql, configuration, data-warehouse

I'm working at a research lab and was given a project that runs a bunch of scripts against a dataset that's not huge, but starts to get weird as the scripts create more tables.  I could re-write a lot of them as they were written by a researcher that learned SQL for this project, but I'd like to see how I can tune MySQL to really use all of the machine.  It's a 16 cpu, 60gb memory EC2 instance.  I only seem to be able to get about 10% of the 48gb memory reserved (VIRT) for for MySql according to running top.

I have 60g of memory on this, but it's being used to run a series of scripts by one user, me.  Is there a settings profile for this type of use-case that would differ significantly from a well-tuned general MySQL instance?

I'm getting through it by re-writing scripts, but would like to throw some hardware of it as well.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assuming you are using `InnoDB`, you should set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 42G.  However, it won't grow much beyond the actual size of the tables and their indexes.
- More tables --> slower, at least to some extent.  This is because each table involves at least one file on the file system.
- For DataWarehouse type analysis, "Summary tables" can often shrink the running time 10-fold.
- Normalization, but not over-normalization, is often good.

I am being rather vague, in keeping with your question.  Would you care to enhance your question?